# How to use auto-layout to move TextField when a ImageView is hidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a label, picture , textfield.
The picture is located 50px from the label and the textfield is located at a distance of 50px from the pictures.
When the picture is hidden I need to pick up the text box on 50px on the label.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex0LC.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/natp2.png

Comment: Have you tried ? Because it should work out of the box. Set the `image` property of `UIImageView` to nil and auto layout will do the rest.

Comment: Yes, I am tried.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/TEU5c.png

Comment: You should only have a constraint between the label and the image view and between the image view and the textfield.

Comment: It is correctly? http://i.stack.imgur.com/fKgbc.png

Answer (score 0):

create a instance of of the layout constraint if imageview null then change this just like this
`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightchange;` 
and set this on imageview position.
What i am trying to understand you just using some coding reset the auto layout constraint that you have set from Xcode

Comment: Does't work.
Could you  tell us more or give an example?